# Firebase | no index.html found in the current directory after reloading

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I got a Vue3 Setup on firebase. In dev-mode it runs as expected:
`/startPage` is the default page in vue-router:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const publicPages = ['/startPage'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);

  if (authRequired && store.getters.isLoggedIn === "") {
    console.log("Not logged in...");
    router.push('/startPage');
  } else {
    next();
  }
  //this.username = store.getters.getUser.username;
});
```

When now deploying it on firebase the page appears when visiting `/startPage`, but when reloading the page I get:

`This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory.`

EDIT:
firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single-page apps, all paths need to utilize rewrites as SPA generate a single HTML document: as found in the documentation and answered here

```
        "rewrites":[
            {
                "source":"**",
                "destination":"/index.html"
            }
        ]
```

Should you need to add additional paths, they should precede the wild card as a priority.

The same can be found in VueJS [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#firebase).

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Adding rewrite rules to firebase.json solved it:

```
        "rewrites":[
            {
                "source":"**",
                "destination":"/index.html"
            }
        ]
```